# App Crashes When Converting Types - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, types, parse-platform

My app in swift sometimes builds and works perfectly and other times it crashes. It'll crash 2 out of 3 times. I am pulling Numbers from Parse which I'm putting into an array declared as a NSInteger because the data is being converted as a NSInteger. I've tried converting the array into a Int/NSInteger interchangeably as well as the data that I'm pulling in. I'm then posting the data onto a label which is divided up  in cells, which i have to convert into a String...

Since different pictures and different data is coming into the cells, i created another class called "cells", as shown below, where my UI is hooked up: the 2 labels and the Image. cells is a UITableView.

As mentioned, sometimes it crashes, other times it doesn't... I'm pulling data from 3 different classes. Could that be a problem?

The data is queried from the viewDidLoad separately.

I've commented out the lines below to see if 1 is the problem, but they're all problematic.

Here are my variables that I'm populating with the data from Parse:

```
       var hotScores = [NSInteger]() 
       var totalHotScores = [NSInteger]()
       var images = [UIImage]()
        var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
```

Here's the code where it crashes:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell:cells =    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as cells

    myCell.hotScore.text = String(hotScores[indexPath.row] as NSInteger)
    myCell.totalScore.text = String(totalHotScores[indexPath.row] as NSInteger)
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            myCell.postedImage.image = image
        }


    }
    return myCell
}
```

Here is how i'm querying it in the viewDidLoad:

```
    var hotQuery = PFQuery(className:"Hots")
    hotQuery.limit = 10
    hotQuery.orderByDescending("numOfHots")
    hotQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {


                self.hotScores.append(object["numOfHots"] as NSInteger)


                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

    } else {

        println(error)
    }
    }

    var imageQuery = PFQuery(className:"Images")
    imageQuery.limit = 10
    imageQuery.orderByAscending("ImageFiles")
    imageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {

            self.imageFiles.append(object["ImageFiles"] as PFFile)


                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        } else {

            println(error)
        }
    }


    var totalVotesQuery = PFQuery(className:"TotalVotes")
    totalVotesQuery.limit = 10
    totalVotesQuery.orderByDescending("numOfTotalVotes")
    totalVotesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {

                self.totalHotScores.append(object["numOfTotalVotes"] as NSInteger)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        } else {
         println(error)
        }
    }
```

This is what the error says:

```
  Thread 1: EXC_Bad_INSTRUCTION(CODE=EXC_1386_INVOP,SUBCDE=0X0)
```

Lastly, the UI elements are named:

```
            hotScore //as the first label
            totalScore // as the 2nd label
            postedImage // as the UIImage
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please show the code for the query, and where `hotScores` and `totalHotScores` are created/populated.

Comment: @TimothyWalters just updated. thanks a lot

Comment: @TimothyWalters hey did you see the update? thanks once again...

Comment: Could you comment the line(s) where the error happens please?

Comment: myCell.hotScore.text = String(hotScores[indexPath.row] as NSInteger) it only targets that line.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side-note to keep in mind, the cell might have been re-used by the time the image loads, ah the fun of async code a multi-treading :)

You should check if the cell still wants the image you got back. You could try checking `imageFiles[indexPath.row]` and read it's URL property and compare it to the local object's URL in your block. Then only set the image if they still match.

Anyway, for your crashing problem, I don't know exactly what line you are crashing on yet but I would definitely add some Optionals safety checking code there, particularly these lines:

```
if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
  myCell.postedImage?.image = image
}
```

I don't know if `postedImage` is optional or not, so I added the "?" just in case. Definitely use the `if let` though.

From your comments it turns out this line is the problem:

```
myCell.hotScore.text = String(hotScores[indexPath.row] as NSInteger)
```

In that case it probably means that `hotScores[indexPath.row]` doesn't have anything compatible with NSInteger in it for that row. Again safe optionals to the rescue:

```
if let hotScore = hotScores[indexPath.row] as? NSInteger {
  // safely got the hot score, use it
} else {
  // handle the issue of hotScore being invalid for this row
}
```

Comment: I think this is happening because I'm querying 3 different things from 3 different classes. I just made a small test to see if thats the problem and when i made 1 class with all my objects inside and queried just that class, it doesn't seem to crash, even if I run it 10x. But if i were to have only 1 class i would have to change a lot of code in different view controllers. However, that ultimately may be the best thing to do... Going to try this code as well that you provided. Thank you so much.

Comment: It keeps crashing, even with the 'if let' in front of the image. The error is shown for the 2 labels. It even runs 3 or 4 times, but then the 5th time it'll crash. So strange... Any ideas why it blames those 2 lines?

Comment: It doesn't let me make a conditional with the as? giving me an error saying: "Conditional downcast from 'NSInteger' to 'NSInteger' always succeeds." It worked for a few builds alone if I wrapped the NSInteger? as an optional at the end. However, once i added the totalVotes with the same syntax (NSInteger?) it crashed after a few builds. Should I change the arrays to another type?